# Laravel Combine Multi Dimensional Array Based On Year Value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

This one is my array want to combine based on year value

```
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "year" => 2022
    "total_policies_financed" => 1
    "total_amount_financed" => 280.0
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "year" => 2022
    "total_policies_financed" => 2
    "total_amount_financed" => 5190.0
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "year" => 2021
    "total_policies_financed" => 2
    "total_amount_financed" => 5190.0
  ]
```

**need output like this**

```
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "year" => 2022,
    "total_count" => 2,
    "total_policies_financed" => 3
    "total_amount_financed" => 5470
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
   "year" => 2021,
    "total_count" => 1,
    "total_policies_financed" => 2
    "total_amount_financed" => 5190.0
  ]
```

Comment: Where are the codes you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$arr = collect($array)->groupBy('year')->map(function ($items, $key){
    return [
        'year' => $key,
        'total_count' => $items->count(),
        'total_policies_financed' => $items->sum('total_policies_financed'),
        'total_amount_financed' => $items->sum('total_amount_financed'),
    ];
})->values();

dd($arr);
```